# Why MLP has better performance compared to CNN and LSTM?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, conv-neural-network, speech, mlp

I am comparing the performance of MLP, CNN, and LSTM in classification of single word speech. The performance of MLP is somehow equal to CNN. However, it has better performance than LSTM. Can anyone let me know what is the reason. The dataset contains 2753 seperate sounds for all 20 words. I used MFCC for feature extraction.